# Publicar un complemento de google spreadsheets en dominio secundario

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-cloud-platform

Desarrollé un complemento para spreadsheets para mi organización: starco.com.mx, la cual es un dominio secundario de electromag.com.mx. Cuando publiqué el complemento, este es visible en electromag.com.mx pero no para los usuarios de starco.com.mx. Ya busqué en la documentación pero no hay nada al respecto para publicar el proyecto para los usuarios del dominio secundario. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

El addon tambien está publicado en G Suite Market place.

La configuración: Categoría: Administración y gestión; Regiones: México; Idioma: Español; Opciones de visibilidad: Sin mostrar.

En el caso de GSMP: Extensión del complemento de Hojas de cálculo; Visibilidad Pública (no me deja alterarla).

Y no soy superadministrador de la consola de G Suite

Comment: Bienvenido. Me parece interesante la pregunta, sin embargo, aunque se espera que las preguntas sean breves, esta brevedad no debe de sacrificar los detalles mínimos necesarios entender la situación ni lo buscado/investigado. ¿Publicaste el complemento en G Suite Market Place? ¿Cuál fue la configuración de publicación tanto en el Chrome Webstore como en G Suite Marketplace? ¿Tienes acceso a la consola de administración de G Suite como superadministrador?

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Si, ya es obligatorio publicar en G Suite Market Place los complementos. La configuración... Categoría: Administración y gestión; Regiones: México; Idioma: Español; Opciones de visibilidad: Sin mostrar. En el caso de GSMP: Extensión del complemento de Hojas de cálculo; Visibilidad Pública (no me deja alterarla). Y no, no soy superadministrador de la consola de G Suite.

Comment: Por favor [edit] la pregunta para agregar los detalles que compartes. En este sitio los comentarios son para dar sugerencias, pedir aclaraciones o dar información transitoria.

Comment: Listo!, Ya lo agregué en la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

He publicado varios complementos pero no he me topado aún con la necesidad de publicar uno para una organización como dominios secundarios. Lo que he visto en las opciones de configuración es que es posible limitar los complementos a los usuarios de un dominio con una única casilla de verificación, quizás no sea posible tener un único complemento privado que sea accesible para los otros dominios de la misma organización.

Una alternativa es que tu complemento sea público pero mediante código limites lo que se puede hacer. Si esto es viable o no depende de lo que haga tu complemento y las políticas de tu empresa / depto. de TI.

Una solución provisional sería hacer copias del proyecto del complemento y para mantener el código sincronizado usar CLASP, una extensión para Chrome o directamente usar la API de Google Apps Script.

Para lo anterior camino es que cada copia para cada dominio utilices una cuenta del dominio correspondiente para crear el proyecto de Cloud Console de tal forma que se asocie a la organización correspondiente, luego podrás compartir el proyecto con tu cuenta principal, pero la publicación al Chrome WebStore seguramente tendrás que hacerla una cuenta del dominio al que corresponde la copia.

Otro camino probable es que un superadministrador le de permiso a tu cuenta de desarrollador para crear proyectos de Cloud Console en cada en las organizaciones que corresponden a los subdominios.